# The third conditional for "if I could"

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, past-participles, conditional-perfect, optative-mood

What is the third conditional for "if I could"? For example, we say:

> If I had studied hard, I would have passed the exam. *How about this:*
>
> If I could study, I would have passed the exam.[Is there a past perfect for could?]

Comment: You should understand that native speakers are not taught this “third conditional” thing, and therefore have little to no idea what you are actually asking for here.

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although *could* is the past tense of *can*, past tense in modals often doesn't mean past time. In the *if I could*, the past tense *could* has a counterfactual meaning rather than a past time meaning. Of course, the verb following the modal can't be past tense, so to give it a past time meaning, use the perfect aspect (i.e., *could + have +* past participle). So your example about studying could be changed to

> *If I could have studied, I would have passed.*

Another option, as Irene has pointed out, is to avoid *could* and use *be able,* leading to

> *If I had been able to study, I would have passed.*

The idea of zero, first, second, and third conditional has been much criticszed. See, for example, [here](http://eltj.oxfordjournals.org/content/65/1/24.abstract).

Comment: By the way, modals are followed by the bare infinitive form of the verb, so the *have studied* is infinitive perfect, not present perfect.

Comment: re: your comment, what is the difference between "have studied" being an infinitive perfect rather than present perfect?

Comment: Consider "it's good to have studied" infinitive perfect

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use **could** in the Past Perfect, you use the expression **be able to** in the correct form. So your sentence will be:

*If I had been able to study, I would have passed the exam*.

The same rule applies when you want to use the Present Perfect form:

*I haven't been able to talk to him recently.*

Or the Future form:

*I will be able to travel around the world some day*.

Comment: Can we use 'could' without changing it to 'be able to'?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two moods of speech at play here: the subjunctive and optative moods. Sometimes, you have to decide which of those two you are expressing.

Frequently, non-native speakers of English ignore the concepts of subjunctive and optative moods.

It is usual for people to say,

> If you take your shoes off before coming in, I will be a very happy
> host.

However, you could also say,

> If you took your shoes off before coming in, I would be a very happy
> host.

The subjunctive mood is found in most Romance and Germanic languages as well as ancient Sanskrit.

In English, the subjunctive/optative moods are designated by using the past tense.

**Subjunctive mood**
The mood implies the notion of impossibility or improbability. The famous example found in many books introducing the subjunctive is

> If I were a bird, I would sing all day.

You should not say

> If I am a bird, I will sing all day

because it is impossible for you to be a bird. And since the English language does not have a different set of tenses for the subjunctive/optative moods, we fall into using the past tense - in this case *were* and *would*.

**Politeness and the optative mood**
Frequently, non-native speakers of English do not realise that the following is essentially rude or assertive:

> Can you please take off your shoes before coming in?

You should say

> Could you please take your shoes off before coming in?

It is spoken in a combination of the optative and subjunctive moods. It bears an underlying message that the speaker is saying

- you have a choice, it is not imperative that you take your shoes off. However, it would be the joy of my heart if you refrain from muddying up the floor of my living room.
- I realise it is impossible for me to compel you to take your shoes off. However, if you decide to do the impossible for me, you will be my hero.

**The present, past and future tenses**

Future assertive mood:

> When you bake a cake, I will certainly eat it.
>
> After you have baked me a cake, I will certainly eat it.

Future optative:

> If you baked me a cake, I would certainly eat it.
>
> If you could bake me a cake, I would certainly eat it.

You are saying to your sister - I know it would trouble you a lot, but please, please, pretty please bake me a cake.

Future subjunctive:

> Even if you were to bake me a cake, I would certainly not eat it.
>
> Even if you could bake me a cake, I could certainly not eat it.
>
> Were you to bake me a cake, would I even eat it?

You are telling your sister - It is impossible for you to bake a cake because you lack the skills to bake it, but even if you could, it would certainly be so bad that I would not eat it.

Present assertive:

> You are baking a cake and I am expecting to eat it.

Present optative:

> You could be baking a cake now, and I could be standing here watching and hoping to eat it.

Present subjunctive:

> If you were baking a cake, I would be standing here watching and hoping to eat it. (But you are not because you are too occupied with FB or SO).

Past assertive:

> You should have baked me the cake and I would have eaten it.

Past optative denoted by the past perfect:

> If you had baked me a cake, I would have eaten it.
>
> Had you baked me the cake, I would have eaten it.
>
> If you had baked me a cake, I would have eaten it.

Past subjunctive:

> Had you baked me that silly cake, would I have even eaten it?
>
> Had you studied harder, would you even have passed the exam?

We could even extend an extra leg to conjure a past perfect subjunctive/optative by cascading subjunctives/optatives:

> Had we been in the situation of you having baked me a cake, I would have been feeling the effects of having eaten your cake.

We could have an infinite recursion of subjunctives/optatives:

> Had we been in the status where we could have been in the status of being in the status of being in ..... of having you baked me a cake, I would have been in the status where I could have been in the status of being in the status of being in .... of having eaten that cake.