# "Can" or "could", which is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, politeness, modal-verbs

I'm a call center agent. When I ask to transfer the call to the authorized person, which form should I use:

> Can I speak to...?

or

> Could I speak to...?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: How about _May I speak to_, since the person answering does not know your ability to speak.

Comment: Can is a modal verb implying a definite ability to do something. Could shifts the sentence to the subjunctive mood, implying a potential ability to do something.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99957/what-is-the-difference-between-can-could-may-and-might/99960#99960

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/the-third-conditional-for-if-i-could/60807#60807

Comment: *Grammatically*, any modal verb is equally correct in that position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should we use "can", "could", "will", "would"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/when-should-we-use-can-could-will-would) @Kris: I didn't downvote, but I still think things like this belong on ELL. We only have those really old questions because they were asked before ELL was created. But how will ELL ever graduate from beta if we keep questions like this on ELU?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see this as less of a question of grammar than semantics plus etiquette. *Can I* sounds very different from *Could I* in the context, and has a very different connotation.

Comment: @LeonConrad Please see my comment @ FumbleFingers.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Please see my comment @ FumbleFingers.

Comment: @Kris - I don't disagree - I suspect I see grammar, semantics and etiquette being closely linked; while you see them as being separate, that's all.

Answer (score 5):

Only pedants or jokers would reject "Can I speak to..." or "Could I speak to...", any of these are acceptable, especially if you include the magic word ("Please").

While some people may find it overly formal, I would think "May I please speak to..." should be almost universally acceptable.

P.S. I remember a certain older gentleman who took great delight in torturing my young self with exchanges such as this:

Me: "Can I have a cookie?"
Him: "Yes, you *can*, ..." (but doesn't get the cookie jar)
Me: "... Could I have a cookie, then?"
Him: "Yes, you *could*, ..." (still, no action)
Me: "May I have a cookie, please?"
Him: "Yes, you *may*." (finally, I get my cookie) :)

Comment: *May* is not much better in fetching you the cookie at all, it makes no difference. You "may" have and still *may* not -- Think again. Also, please see my comment at FumbleFingers under OP.

Comment: Sure it does, the word "may" is perfectly acceptable as a request. Also, it's more polite to ask "May I have a cookie?" rather than demand "Give me a cookie!"

Comment: c.f. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/may *"To have permission to, be allowed. Used in granting permission and in questions to make polite requests."*

Comment: Yes, *Yes*. Yet. :)

Comment: I guess the ultra-polite version would be something along the lines of, *"My good sir, if it pleases you, could I trouble you to allow me the pleasure of speaking to ..."* :)